# Matlab Computer Vision: How to use image in memory for imageSet?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am currently working on a project at home and hoping to use the Computer Vision toolbox in Matlab to retrieve images from a set that match based on my query image. In fact, the example I'm using from the Matlab documentation here: [Image Matching Example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-retrieval-using-customized-bag-of-features.html)

The snag I keep bumping into is that it appears the imageSet class in Matlab only works on files saved to disk. Unfortunately, the work I'm doing has a 4D matrix of an image collection I've created artificially. More specifically, it has the shape (M,N,RGB,I) where

- M = number of pixels in X-dir
- N = number of pixels in Y-dir
- RGB =
  size of 3, where each channel for RGB is stored as a page
- I = the
  image number (up to 10,000, for example)

It seems pretty silly that I have to write everything to files for me to employ the imageSet class object.

So, the question is: Does anyone know a way to create the imageSet object (or similar) without have to write everything to a tmp dir on disk to carry out the analysis, that is, create imageSet from workspace variables?

For the life of me this one had me stumped all weekend. I know I could capitulate and write to files, but somehow that just bothers me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `imageSet` only stores file names, and gives you a `read` method to read a particular image from disk.

In general, if you already have the images in memory, you can simply store them in a cell array. Or, if your images are all the same size, you can keep them in a single multi-dimensional array.

However, in this particular case, you are using `bagOfFeatures`, which currently only takes `imageSet`. So you will have to save your images to files.

Comment: So, to be clear, my image matrix as described can be passed into the commands such as "indexImages" or "retrieveImages" anywhere the imageSet object is used? Unfortunately, I won't be able to test until this weekend as I'm on the road at the moment. But will be sure to post my results if I've understood you correctly.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Unfortunately, `bagOfFeatures` only takes imageSet, so you will have to save your images to files.

Comment: Sigh...Thanks for the clarification, Dima.